# trying to delete data from table

Tags: mysql-workbench

in mysql workbench im trying to execute

```
delete from basic_info where rollno>3;
```

this query but im getting this message

> Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to
>   update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe
>   mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using below commands.

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
delete from basic_info where rollno>3;
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an `INDEX` with `rollno` column, good for a long term not only this query

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say which MySQL Workbench you are using, but make sure you always use the latest one to get all latest bugfixes.

Since you obvioulsy have a `where` clause in your query it looks like it is not recognized (which would be a bug). Hence my advice to use the latest version.

In any case you can disable the safety check in the preferences of MySQL Workbench.

[image]